# How to use ARRAYFORMULA + FILTER within Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have a Google spreadsheet with basically a dictionary of key/value pairs. Keys are unique. In a second sheet I need to add one or more rows for every key in the dictionary with some data. In this very sheet I'd need to also report the proper value for each key.

To do so I have tried to combine the ARRAYFORMULA function with a number of other functions on the very first row of the second sheet to avoid (if possible) the need to copy the same formula on all rows of the value column.

So far, neither QUERY nor FILTER worked.

QUERY requires all data, there included the arguments to the WHERE predicate, to reside on a single sheet. In my case, the filtering key would be on the second sheet while the dictionary is on the first one. So this cannot be used at all.

FILTER seems to have a weird (to me) behavior when both used in conjunction with ARRAYFORMULA and without it.

You can have a look to my test Google Sheet 
[here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eFyp4MOUA8N0g_I0eQhA0TIMqCauDqSNSoInecRT104/edit?usp=sharing) or to snapshots here with ARRAYFORMULA (column B), without it (column C) and what I'd like to get (column D):

[image: KEY sheet with the key/value pairs]

[image: DATA sheet with the data for the keys]

A little step further from pnuts' solution provides the "perfect" result without the "N/A" cells:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A="";"";VLOOKUP(A3:A;KEYS!A1:B;2;FALSE)))
```

Of course there is a major impact on the performances as the VLOOKUP is run once for every single line in in the second sheet (and this was also why I was trying to use FILTER).
Those performances are quite low even with the currently linked example sheet, which is really skinny.

Comment: It'd be nice to know why it's been downvoted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Row3 please try:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(A3:A;KEYS!A$1:B$5;2;0))
```

Comment: That works almost great. In D8 I find a "N/A" cell with remark 'Cannot find value "" during execution of VLOOKUP'. Even if I added an empty key in the KEYS sheet.

Comment: Good point. I don't have explicit knowledge of the size of the KEYS sheet. I'd rather need to exclude all blank rows from KEYS.

Comment: I did it starting from pnuts' solution. Thanks.

Comment: There's a major impact on the performances even by sorting the keys. Of course I am testing with the real data where the keys are about 20 and the data about 200. It'd not be like this, anyway...

Answer (score 2):

you can use a `From spreadsheet - On change` event trigger to call code like below:

```
function CopyPasteWastageRows() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("<<Sheet-Name>>");
    spreadsheet.getRange('Q2').activate();
    var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
    spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
    currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
    spreadsheet.getRange('Q2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
    spreadsheet.getRange('Q2').activate();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

What `ARRAYFORMULA` + `FILTER` cannot do, `BYROW` (or `BYCOL`) + `LAMBDA` can!
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930

For your Sheet:

```
=BYROW(A3:A; LAMBDA(row; IFNA(VLOOKUP(row; KEYS!A2:B; 2; FALSE))))
```

Sample of which: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Bt6AqxfQ9fspvCk4sQsU-gOHbpB7_-MFm-bR1jGF08U/edit#gid=1589326430

[image: BYROW saves the world]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A3:A); VLOOKUP(A3:A;KEYS!A1:B;2;FALSE);))
```

That should get the keys, as far as values are entered in col A.